# I am after some assisstance str and StringVar

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a program that gets a password and a username using a tkinter entry, and then saves it on an external file. Here is what I have got so far:

```
def validateLogin(username, password):
    filename = input("What is your first name?: ")
    c = open(filename, "w");
    print("username entered :", username.get())
    print("password entered :", password.get())
    c.write(username)
    return
```

. That is just the part that I am having trouble with at the moment.

Comment: "Anyone have any ideas?" - this code looks fine at the first glance. You should just make sure to close the file after writing. What's the "trouble" you're having with it?

Comment: It keeps giving me an error saying that ```write()``` must be str not stringvar

Comment: Ah, then you should write `username.get()` instead

Comment: Is that when its asking for an input or in c.write?

Answer (score 0):

`c.write(username)` attempts to write an object of type `StringVar`, but files opened with `c = open(filename, "w")` only work with *text*, a.k.a. `str`.

To extract the string from a `StringVar`, use `get`, as you were using earlier in your code:

```
c.write(username.get())
c.close() # don't forget to close the file
```